# LSTM won't overfit training data

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have been trying to use an LSTM for regression in TensorFlow, but it doesn't fit the data. I have successfully fit the same data in Keras (with the same size network).  My code for trying to overfit a sine wave is below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

yt = np.cos(np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 256))
xt = np.array([yt[i-50:i] for i in range(50, len(yt))])[...,None]
yt = yt[-xt.shape[0]:]

g = tf.Graph()
with g.as_default():
    x = tf.constant(xt, dtype=tf.float32)
    y = tf.constant(yt, dtype=tf.float32)

    lstm = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(32)
    outputs, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm, x, dtype=tf.float32)
    pred = tf.layers.dense(outputs[:,-1], 1)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(pred-y))
    train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss)
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

sess = tf.InteractiveSession(graph=g)
sess.run(init)

for i in range(200):
    _, l = sess.run([train_op, loss])
print(l)
```

This results in a MSE of 0.436067 (while Keras got to 0.0022 after 50 epochs), and the predictions range from -0.1860 to -0.1798.  What am I doing wrong here?

Edit:
When I change my loss function to the following, the model fits properly:

```
def pinball(y_true, y_pred):
    tau = np.arange(1,100).reshape(1,-1)/100
    pin = tf.reduce_mean(tf.maximum(y_true[:,None] - y_pred, 0) * tau +
                 tf.maximum(y_pred - y_true[:,None], 0) * (1 - tau))
    return pin
```

I also change the assignments of `pred` and `loss` to

```
pred = tf.layers.dense(outputs[:,-1], 99)
loss = pinball(y, pred)
```

This results in a decrease of loss from 0.3 to 0.003 as it trains, and seems to properly fit the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a shape/broadcasting issue. Here's a working version:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

yt = np.cos(np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 256))
xt = np.array([yt[i-50:i] for i in range(50, len(yt))])
yt = yt[-xt.shape[0]:]

g = tf.Graph()
with g.as_default():
    x = tf.constant(xt, dtype=tf.float32)
    y = tf.constant(yt, dtype=tf.float32)

    lstm = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(32)
    outputs, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm, x[None, ...], dtype=tf.float32)
    pred = tf.squeeze(tf.layers.dense(outputs, 1), axis=[0, 2])
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(pred-y))
    train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss)
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

sess = tf.InteractiveSession(graph=g)
sess.run(init)

for i in range(200):
    _, l = sess.run([train_op, loss])
print(l)
```

`x` gets a batch dimension of 1 before going into `dynamic_rnn`, since with `time_major=False` the first dimension is expected to be a batch dimension. It's important that the last dimension of the output of `tf.layers.dense` get squeezed off so that it doesn't broadcast with `y` (`TensorShape([256, 1])` and `TensorShape([256])` broadcast to `TensorShape([256, 256])`). With those fixes it converges:

> 5.78507e-05

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing-on the state from one call of dynamic_rnn to next. That's the problem for sure.

Also, why take only last item of the output through the dense layer and onward?

Comment: From my understanding, I only would be able to pass the state if I had multiple batches.  I'm only passing the last step's output through because I am trying to use the past 50 steps to predict the next one.  I added an example of something that works that is very similar, but using a different loss.

Comment: Ah i see on the last one, i should have looked more carefully as thought you predicted one-to-one as opposed to one-to-many. You call dynamic_rnn multiple times in a loop. Why not pass the state back and forth?

Comment: I just wanted to create the smallest example that could demonstrate my issue.  Because using a different loss function without passing states works, I would expect MSE to also work without passing states.  Also, from what I know, Keras doesn't pass states by default, so I don't think that is necessary.